# How to send the selected options from a multiselect to a load ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, checkbox

I got the nice plugin from the eric hanes ...from this site :

http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

I want the values get alert from the selected check box from the select options ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.multiselect.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/prettify.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("select").multiselect();
});
</script>
</head>
<body id="test">

<p>
    <select title="Basic example" multiple="multiple" name="example-basic" size="5">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
    <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
    <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
    <option value="option10">Option 10</option>
    <option value="option11">Option 11</option>
    <option value="option12">Option 12</option>
    </select>
</p>

<button onclick="check_count()"> click </button>

</body>
</html>
```

For eg : if I select option 1 and option 2, I should get alert of option 1 and again second alert option 2..

One more help ...Now this values has to pass to the ajax call and there the ajax variables has to be dynamic...
I am using the load() ajax function ..

```
$("#fetch").load("select.php",{var1:var1,var2:var2......},function(){});
```

here how to pass the check box variables dynamically in the ajax call.

```
<?php 

$var1= $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];
.
.
.


echo $var1;
echo $var2;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/2mkvfkej/)** :-

```
$('select').change(function () {
  alert($('select option:selected').text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks ...I have changed my code ..could you please tell me...after click the button ..how to pass the variables dynamically to the ajax call...as the ajax load() function requires only selected variable can pass..but i want to pass the selected checked boxes pass the ajax call variables....if you got doubt please check the code...I have edited...

Comment: You mean u want to do ajax call on button click and pass the checked checkboxes data to server ? Correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: yes, on click of the button and send check box values to the server ...and u told correct but the check boxes are variable I mean its depends on the user input its changes sometimes 10 , or 24 or 8 or 15 ...If u din't understand please ask I will explain correct question...

Comment: i didn't understand this `10 or 24 or 8 or 15` part  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var alertOptions='';
$("select").multiselect({
   click: function(event, ui){
      alertOptions+=ui.value + ' ' + (ui.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked');

      $callback.text(alertOptions);
      alert(alertOptions);

   }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Count `$('select option:selected')` as Tushar Raj mentioned 
OR
just run `$('select').val()` to get array of values, if you use jQuery.

Comment: Thanks ...I have changed my code ..could you please tell me...after click the button ..how to pass the variables dynamically to the ajax call...as the ajax load() function requires only selected variable can pass..but i want to pass the selected checked boxes pass the ajax call variables....if you got doubt please check the code...I have edited the code...

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through selected options, create a JSON and send it:

```
 $('#idFromYourComponent').load("YourURL",createJSON(),function(){});

function createJSON() {
        jsonObj = {};
        $('select').multiselect("widget").find("input:checked").each(function(i) {

            var value = $(this).val();

            item = 'option'+i        

            jsonObj[item]=value;
        });

        return jsonObj;
    }
```

Comment: Its not working...? please help how to pass selected variables to the ajax call i.e...load() ajax function ...dynamically ...

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("select").multiselect();
});
</script>
```

to this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("select").multiselect({
   click: function(event, ui){
      alert(ui.value + ' ' + (ui.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked') );
   }
    });
});
</script>
```